# Xcode: Using swift playground detect when running XCTest or PlaygroundPage

Tags: xcode9, xctest, swift-playground, swift4.1

Any of you knows if is a condition I can set the swift playground to differentiate when is been executed either by:

`MyClassTest.defaultTestSuite.run()` or by

`PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyClass()`

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do. Give some more details

Comment: @staticVoidMan, What I'm trying to do is, if I'm running defaultTestSuite use different mock data then when I run PlaygroundPage.current.liveView.

Comment: Then you're going about this the wrong way. This should be solved by employing the Dependency Injection pattern. Your main logic should not decide whether to use mock data or not. Infact it should not know about the environment at all. It should just be concerned about its purpose.

Comment: Tell us more about your test. About `MyClass()` and this mock data you have in mind, and lets see if we can help.